# Hyper-V Windows 10 RDP Performance

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 host machine running Hyper-V and in it I have a Windows 10 VM, which I want to use to connect to my corp VPN so that I can RDP into my workstation. For some reason, the performance of my VM while connected to RDP is just unbearable. Working in the VM is just fine, but once I open MSTSC and connect, the remote machine is like a slide show. I am able to RDP to this same machine outside of the VM, without any performance issues.

Are there any common gotchas here, or something I might turn on (or off), to improve performance?

Comment: do you have a high-DPI screen? Like a 3000x2000 pixel screen?

Comment: I have been testing it on a 1920x1080 and also 2560x1600 resolution display. So yea, one of them is big, but it doesn't seem to be necessarily worse on either one.

Comment: it's worth a try. try this: https://blog.brankovucinec.com/2016/03/19/fix-remote-desktop-dpi-scaling-issues/

Comment: +1. Also you can use 3rd party RDP clients like mRemoteNG https://mremoteng.org/

Comment: I gave mRemoteNG a try, and the performance is noticeably better. It appears to be using a reduced GUI for Windows, I'm getting a Windows XP style chrome.  So it would seem that MSTSC is not optimizing for performance. Turning down the color depth in MSTC helps some, but I'm not aware of anything else I can configure.

Comment: I should note, it still isn't anywhere near as performant a direct RDP from the host machine. I understand that there is some latency with a VM, but this seems excessive.